# Forcing the scrollbar to overflow:scroll in Angular / dynamic max-height property

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following chat component:

HTML:

```
<div id="chat-bar" class="game-sidebar-chat">
  <h2>Game chat</h2>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush border-bottom scrollarea">
    <div *ngFor="let msg of messages" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3">
      <h6>{{msg.username}}</h6>
      <div class="message-text">{{msg.text}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form class="d-flex flex-column">
    <input [(ngModel)]="chatMessageInput" name="message" class="form-control form-control-lg mb-1" placeholder="Write a message" (submit)="sendChatMessage()">
    <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" class="text-wrap"  (click)="sendChatMessage()">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.game-sidebar-chat {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 34vh;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .game-sidebar-chat {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 80vh;
    }
}

.scrollarea {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}

.message-text {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

As you can see for every message that's being received a new div is appended (the *ngFor directive). My goal was to make the `.scrollarea` take as much space (height) as possible (hence `height: 100%` in `.scrollarea`) and make it stay within the bounds of `.game-sidebar-chat` (`overflow-y: scroll`). The problem is that when the height of those divs exceed the initial height of `.scrollarea` it just stretches it out and the `overflow-y: scroll` behaviour kicks in only when the divs' height reaches the `max-height` of the `.game-sidebar-chat`. [Here's how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6RtK.png)

That component is a column inside a row consisting of three columns (bootstrap classes), of which the second one (the board) defines the height of the other two (hence the `height: 100%` in `.game-sidebar-chat`). I want to keep this layout responsive/resizable, so when for example the browser's window shrinks, all of the three columns maintain the same height. I managed to achieve this using Angular's Renderer2 and ElementRef, where I listen to the window resize event, broadcast the `height` of the board, and set the `max-height` of `#chat-bar`, but I feel like that's an overkill and it should be achievable with just CSS. I'm also not sure if it's a good solution performance-wise, so any insight here would be helpful too. Here's the code and [the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTxW8.png):

game-live.pieces.component.ts:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.broadcastBoardHeight();
    }, 200)
    this.renderer.listen(window, 'resize', event => {
      this.broadcastBoardHeight();
    })
  }

  broadcastBoardHeight(): void {
    this.cssService.boardHeightBroadcast.next(this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight)
  }
```

game-live-chat.component.ts:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let el = document.getElementById('chat-bar')
    this.cssService.boardHeightBroadcast.subscribe({
      next: height => {
        if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
          this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'max-height', `${height}px`)
        }
        else {
          this.renderer.setStyle(el, 'max-height', '34vh')
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

I've looked online for other people's similar issues but none of them really matched my situation since most of them had a fixed `height`/`max-height` of the scrollbar which isn't the case here.

If you need to take a look at other components' code here's the link to the project: https://github.com/mephis71/django_channels_angular_chess

Comment: Have you considered using flexbox or css grid?  I think you are definitely right that it would be better and more performant to just do this with css.  Angular is spectacular, but css is the right tool for the job here.

Comment: @JakeSmith I tried flexbox and had no success with it, the solution I came up with was my last resort. I've never used css grid before, but I'll look into it and if I come up with something I'll post it here.

Comment: perfect!  Good luck!  I'll try to free up from work here in a moment and see if I can slap something together.